# I want to know the source of why Archimedes' broken chord theorem is Archimedes good

Tags: geometry, archimedes

[image]

I found "The Arabian scholar Abu'l Raihan al'biruni" has attributed to Archimedes the theorem of the broken chord in web. But I couldn't find a book or papers that this Arabian scholar wrote.

Comment: A [bibliography of al-Biruni's work](https://philpapers.org/rec/KENABO) by E. Kennedy is available to purchase, but there does not appear to be free access online.  The [MacTutor entry](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Al-Biruni.html) provides some interesting details, including a reference to a 1973 Russian text which details al-Biruni's mathematical contributions.